# Remove word "Products" from breadcramb in WooCommerce attribute archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce's default behaviour is to add the word "Products" in the breadcrumb of [attribute archive pages](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies). I would like that word removed.

I have a product attribute with name "Brand" and slug "brand". In this attribute I have configured a term with name "CAT® BAGS" and slug "cat-bags".

In the following image you can see the archive page for  `example.com/brand/cat-bags`. Although the name of the attribute is "Brand" WooCommerce adds the word "Product" before it, in the breadcrumb.

How can I remove this word from the breadcrumb of the attribute archive pages so the final result will look like this `Shop > Brand > CAT ® BAGS`?

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Which theme are you using? This is mostly controlled in theme templates.

Comment: Can you share an HTML or site link?

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan I'm using Electro Theme. The devs told me it's not from their template but it's a WooCommerce thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can to try  use the `woocommerce_get_breadcrumb` hook, for example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'change_breadcrumb' );
function change_breadcrumb( $crumbs ) {
   foreach ($crumbs as &$crumb) {
       str_replace('Product', '', $crumb);
   }
   return $crumbs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but unfortunately this solution doesn't remove the word "Product".